# Best Java GUI performance on Raspberry PI

Tags: java, performance, swing, user-interface, raspberry-pi

I hope somebody can help me and you fiund this question useful and interesting.

I'm making a Java application for my degree project using a Raspberry Pi. I'm programming all in Java and Linux, but now that I'm starting some developing tests,I found an important issue.
I built all the user interfaces of the application using Java Swing, and although on Linux it runs quite well, I'm detecting bad perdormance on the Raspi, because the GUIs behave wuite slow on the Rapi and the CPU has a huge load.

I've been searching on the net for performance tests and comparisons between main GUIs in Java, but I didn't found relevant results for my problem. Some programmers talk about is better to use AWT or SWT over Swing. I also found that maybe the best approach is to use the LWUIT, but this framework is for Java ME apps and I'm developing my application using Java SE.

Does anybody know which is the best performance Java GUI for the Raspi? The main elements I'm using are: Jlist of Elements (designed as an ArrayList), a few JButtons, pop-ups, key and mouse listners and custom images (for the backgrounds and for the image preview icon of the elements). I want to keep it simple, fast, with the minimum CPU charge and best performance on the raspi. Any ideas for the best GUI in this scenario?

Thank you so much!
Best regards.

Comment: Have you tried JavaFX 2, this has been optimised for the Pi.  It also look nicer. ;)

Comment: You could try to build and improve [the DukePad](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/DukePad) (uses Java FX8).